# install multiple apks on one device tries to replace previous app

Tags: android

I install my apps by sending the apk file to my gmail account as an attachment and then install the app from there. But by doing this, I find that I can install only one app at any point. the device tries to replace any previously installed app if i try to download and install another one. I found the same thing when sideloading the apps through command prompt. am i missing something here?
any help is appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to have different package names for the apps , also if you do this, put separate names too to avoid confusion on your home screen.

Comment: Yes, the package name is the unique identifier for each android app.  You can have 500 apps with the same title, as long as they all have different package names.

Comment: Although i would suggest against 500 apps with the same name :-P

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of packages in Android-land.  One is the Java package that your classes are in and the other is the Android package that is in the manifest. I assume that you are talking about the Android package, not the Java class package, right?  I was confused by the need to give a package name in the manifest and assumed that it wanted the Java package name.  And since I used the same Java package for both of my first two apps, when I installed the second one, it replaced the first one.

On a related question, what is a typical naming convention for Android packages?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, go to File and find Export to zip file and click it.

Like here:

[image].

Now extract the generated zip file and reopen this Android project. It works for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try renaming the .apk files, that might help.

Comment: yes i tried that, those are two different apps with different apk  names. no luck..